# Android - Format string with mask

Tags: java, android, string, text, format

I have a product number which I would like to format using a mask.

Example:

```
String productNumber = "0913014316";
String mask = "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
```

How do I get this following output: `09.13.014.316`?

Can I use `String.format()`? Or maybe something else on the Android?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think writing this yourself instead of waiting for an answer here would be faster :-)

You could do something like (pseudocode):

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
int j=0;
for (int i = 0; i< mask.lenght ;  i++) {
   if (mask[i] == 'X') {
       out.append(producNumber[j];
       j++;
   }
   else {
       out.append('.');
       i++;
   }
}
return out.toString();
```

Comment: Was hoping that there was some kind of more optimal way of doing this... but anyways... :)

Comment: You should remove the i++ in the else

Answer (score 0):

for others who have the same problem, here is full solution:

```
public String getMaskedText(String rawText, String mask, char variableChar, char constChar) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mask.length() && j < rawText.length(); i++) {
        if (mask.charAt(i) == variableChar) {
            out.append(rawText.charAt(j));
            j++;
        } else {
            out.append(constChar);
        }
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
String result = getMaskedText("123456789", "##-###-###",'#','-');
```